# 2007 Dodge Charger acceleration

Tags: acceleration, traction-control

So about a year ago my 2007 Dodge Charger that has (223,000 miles on it) started acting up. I had to get two of the three computers replaced and right after that, few weeks later the  headlights started flickering off and on, but it stopped after a few months. Then when I drive my car and the engine would get warm on the temp gauge my traction control would automatically turn on by itself and my car would slowly accelerate after the second gear it would take 5-10 seconds to increase 10-15 mph. I put it in neutral and the rev the engine and it won't go higher than 3500 rpm. Can somebody please explain to me what is going on with my car and give me a tip on how to repair it.

Comment: There can be alot of things wrong with the vehicle. I suggest plugging it into a computer to check if there are any codes.

Comment: I agree with @Granny, you need to hook up an ODB reader and see what the car tells you. If you want to do something quickly check the spark plugs and plug cables, but you really need a diagnostic.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like there are definitely issues with the car - the overheating is certainly something you need to get checked out ASAP. It *could* be a spurious reading from a failing sensor or other electrical issue (given some of the history you mention) but it could equally indicate something mechanically wrong and that being the case you could be inflicting ongoing damage to the car by continuing to drive it.

The behaviour you describe of the slow acceleration and limited revving sounds exactly like the ECU has detected a fault and has put the car into a "limp home" mode to protect it from further damage. Again this *could* be the result of an electrical malfunction but there isn't really anyway for you to tell that yourself.

You could get an OBD II reader and use that to get the fault codes from the ECU which will give you a starting point but unless you are fairly mechanically inclined it's unlikely that there is anything you'll be able to do at home to resolve these issues so I would advise taking it to a trusted mechanic/garage as soon as you can and I wouldn't drive the car except possibly very gently to take it to said garage.